# What is the VsecCacheManager?

Tags: 2013, error, cache

I've got a puzzling error message in the ULS logs that is causing some issues, it looks like this:

> VsecCacheManager::newSiteCollectionRecord: Failed to generate enough
>   free space for site collection record. m_iMemEstimate: 324096
>   m_iMemAllowed: 204800

More puzzling is that I can't seem to see any reference to a vseccachemanager anywhere I look, let alone direct reference to this particular error.

The only cache running on this farm is the distributed cache manager, so my best bet at the moment is that it's something to do with that.

Can anyone shed any further light on this error message?

Comment: Do you have any custom solutions installed in the farm which might cause this error? Do you get more messages with same correlation-ID which might be helpful to troubleshoot? When does the error occur in ULS-Log?

Comment: I would agree with you it's probably related to the Distributed Cache. You mention it's causing you issues but you don't state what those are?  What problems are you seeing?  It might also help to share what your configuration is, including system memory on each node and what the Cache settings are.